# Unable to concatenate files with find ./subdir/* -print0 | sort | xargs -0 cat > merge.txt

Tags: files, find, zsh

I am trying to concatenate thousands of files that result from processing the pieces output by `split` with

```
find ./subdir/* -print0 | sort | xargs -0 cat > full_merge.txt
```

The files under `subdir`  are:

```
something.foo.aaaaa.output
something.foo.aaaab.output
something.foo.aaaac.output

...
```

But I get `File name too long`

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you get that error.

```
find ./subdir/* -print0
```

(assuming `--print0` was a typo) would output a big non-terminated line with a few NUL characters in it. Because it doesn't end in a newline character and because it contains NUL characters, it is not text, so the behaviour of text utilities like `sort` is unspecified there. GNU sort, would treat it as one big line and add back the missing newline.

Maybe you're using busybox `sort` which as far as I can tell treats those NUL characters on input as line separators as well but outputs lines terminated by newline characters.

`xargs -0` expects NUL separated records. So with GNU sort, `xargs` would treat the `sort` output as the same list as generated by `find -print0` plus on spurious element consisting of that extra newline character added by `sort`.

In the case of busybox `sort`, because all NULs have been converted to newlines, there's only one record as far as `xargs -0` can tell, so it will call `cat` with one huge filename containing newline characters.

Here, if you want to sort the list of filenames, you need either to use GNU `sort` with its `-z` option:

```
find subdir -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 cat > merge.txt
```

Or assume that filenames don't contain newline characters and run:

```
find subdir -type f | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r0 cat > merge.txt
```

Since you used the `zsh` tag, you may as well do everything in `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs subdir/**/*(D.) -- cat > merge.txt
```

Which actually will provide you with a sorting order closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs`' `-0` argument is for when the **input** is NUL-separated, which it's not. If you want this to work you have to separate with NULs in the preceding commands. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to make this [POSIX compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/how-to-use-xargs-with-filenames-containing-whitespaces#comment24142030_16758699):

```
find ./subdir/* -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat -- > full_merge.txt
```

Comment: Usually it's `find -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0`

Comment: Yeah, I tried to make it as POSIX compatible as possible. Unfortunately POSIX `xargs` doesn't support `-0` yet.

Comment: And as per POSIX, `sort` is not required to handle non-text data. And `-t` is to specify the **field** separator, not the line/record separator.

Comment: Oops, corrected.